# How do I make a new image in Eucalyptus from an EBS-backed Windows instance?

Tags: windows, virtualization, eucalyptus

In Eucalyptus 3.4 I have an EBS-backed Windows instance.

There have been a lot of System Updates and I would like to make a new image from the instance.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use euca-create-image to create an image from your running instance.

https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/4.0/index.html#euca2ools-guide/euca-create-image.html